# BOOL vs. dispatch_once_t

Tags: objective-c, boolean

So I'm not sure if it belongs here or on "Code Review" but I figured it was more of a how things work question than anything so I decided to post here.

I am reading about `dispatch_once_t` and `dispatch_once()` and I can't help but think that...

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    //do stuff
});
```

is an overcomplicated statement for...

```
static BOOL ranOnce = NO;
if (!ranOnce) {
    //do stuff
    ranOnce = YES;
}
```

My question is if **there is any benefit to using one or the other**? If so, in what situations should I use what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former works properly even in a multithreaded environment. As noted in [this blog post](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-06-secrets-of-dispatch_once.html):

> In a single-threaded world, this call would be kind of boring and could be replaced with a simple `if` statement. However, we live in a multithreaded world, and `dispatch_once` is thread safe. It's guaranteed that multiple simultaneous calls to `dispatch_once` from multiple threads will only execute the block once, and all threads will wait until execution is complete before `dispatch_once` returns. Even that is not too hard to accomplish on your own, but `dispatch_once` is also extremely fast, and that is really tough to pull off.

Answer (score 1):

The first one works in a multi-threaded environment.

For the second one, consider what happens if two threads get to `if (!ranOnce) {` before one of them gets to `ranOnce = YES;`.